# How to delete multiple records simultaneously using Rails 3 and multiple check_box_tag elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, checked, jqueryform, delete-record

<strike>I'm stuck worse than a Yugo in a ditch.</strike>

I added the changes which ultimately made this work below (marked as bold **edits**).

**Background**

- *Widgets* have many *Gadgets*
- The final td column in the table has `check_box_tags` to select individual Gadget records for deletion

**Desired Behavior**

- User should be able to click "checkall" as well as individual checkboxes to select Gadgets one at a time
- Clicking the "Delete Selected" button should delete checked records without refreshing the page

**EDIT:** *Adding more specific details about what's not working*

**Observed Behavior**

- destroy_multiple method in gadgets_controller.rb is never being called
- instead, the create method appears to be called

  `Started POST "/widgets/1/gadgets" ...`
  `Processing by GadgetsController#create as JS`
  `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...=", "widget"=>{"gadget_ids"=>["all", "140", "139"]}, "widget_id"=>"1"}`
  `Widget Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "widgets".* FROM "widget" WHERE "widget"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]`
  `Rendered gadgets/create.html.haml within layouts/application (1.1ms)`
  `Rendered layouts/_header.html.haml (0.2ms)`
  `Completed 200 OK in 36ms (Views: 19.0ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)`

I'm also unclear about this: `{"gadget_ids"=>["all", "140", "139"]}`.

"all" is the css id of 1 checkbox used to "checkall". In the checkbox.js.coffee file below, I attempt to remove the "all" value from the Array using javascript. When I log the Array to console, "all" is removed successfully. Yet it continues to be sent to the gadgets controller.

**EDIT**  *rails remote form populates the gadgets array for the POST request. just had to set it up correctly.*

## Models

**widget.rb**

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gadgets
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

**gadget.rb**

```
class Gadget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :widget
  validates_presence_of :widget_id
end
```

## Gadgets Controller

```rb
class GadgetsController < ApplicationController
  include ApplicationHelper

  before_filter :get_widget
  before_filter :widget_gadgets, only: [ :index ]
  respond_to :json

  def json_widgets
    [ @widget, @gadgets ]
  end

  def index
    respond_with(json_widgets) do |format|
      format.json
      format.html
    end
  end

  def new
    @gadget = @widget.gadgets.new()
  end

  def create
    @gadget=@widget.gadgets.new(params[:gadget])
    if @gadget.save
      flash[:success] = "Gadget was successfully created"
      redirect_to widget_gadgets_path
    end
  end

  def destroy_multiple
    gadget_ids=(params[:gadget_ids])
    to_delete=[]
    gadget_ids.split(',').each do |gadget_id|
      to_delete.push(Gadget.find(gadget_id))
    end
    to_delete.each do |del|
      del.destroy()
    end
    flash.now[:success] = "Gadget Destroyed Successfully"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to widget_gadgets_path(@widget) }
      format.json { render :json => to_delete.to_json }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @gadget = gadget.find(params[:gadget_id])
    @widget.gadgets.destroy(@gadget.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(widget_gadgets_path) }
    end 
  end

  def get_widget
    begin
      @widget = Widget.find(params[:widget_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      render file: "public/404.html", status: 404
    end
  end

  private
  def widget_gadgets
    @widget=Widget.find(params[:widget_id])
    @gadgets=@widget.gadgets unless @widget.gadgets.nil?
  end      
end
```

## routes.rb

I'm trying to use a *collection do* block. Is that the right way to implement a destroy_multiple route?

```rb
DestroyMultiple::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :widgets
  resources :gadgets, :only => [ :new, :create ]

  resources :widgets do
    resources :gadgets do
      collection do
        post :destroy_multiple
      end
    end
  end

  match "/:id" => 'widget#gadgets'
  root to: 'widgets#index'
end
```

Comment: Maybe is better to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?

Comment: So what's the question? What doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Frederick - it was totally unclear what the actual problem was! Sorry about that. I have added some more details. Thanks,

Comment: Sorry for the long-winded question and for answering my own question. destroy_multiple widgets is now behaving properly, and I have included the changes I made above. 


The main problem was that I was trying to create my own javascript functions for stuff that Rails wants to do for you automatically via remote forms.

Comment: You should take your solution and provide it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

After getting this to work properly, I wanted to post the full solution.

Rather than type it all out here, please see the full application on GitHub.

While this solution works, I would be very interested to know how I can optimize the solution. Thanks again to those who helped!

https://github.com/hernamesbarbara/AJAX-Rails-Full-CRUD